# Error inflating class TextView with AutoSizing

Tags: android, textview, android-inflate

I started using the [Autosizing TextView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYrpEAz_A1U&t=1s) and it works pretty well in most cases, exception in the following.

I have a recyclerview and in the item layout I have the following TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_tv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textColor="@color/e_white"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="14sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_min="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:text="@tools:sample/cities" />
```

This works well, but if I decrease the `app:autoSizeMaxTextSize` to `12sp`, the following exception is raised:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class TextView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at my.package.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:41)
        at my.package.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:22)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2207)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1963)
```

Can someone explain me this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when specifying `app:autoSizeMaxTextSize=12sp`, because the max then becomes equal to the minimum text size it may have with `autoSize` (which is default `12sp` too).

`autoSize` does not allow the max to be equal or less than the minimum (then it isn't auto sizing anyway).

**Solution:**

To be able to set the max to 12sp, you need to decrease the minimum text size it may have with `app:autoSizeMinTextSize=6sp` for example.

Comment: Perfect explanation!

Comment: Some Android flavours , Samsung, seem to override this value. This will lead to crash. It's not possible for a developer to know all user settings and change one xml value accordingly. Example, we set min 8 , max 16 in our xml. Now we get Crashes with those lines :

`Maximum auto-size text size (36.0px) is less or equal to minimum auto-size text size (36.0px)`
So not an answer for us sadly